# Problem linking when attempting to include btstack C files (.h & .c) in c++ program

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker

I'm attempting to integrate an L2CAP server (in C - uses BlueKitchen's btstack) with a UDP server (in C++). To start, I've attempted to just add the code from the L2CAP server into the "main.cpp" file of the UDP server. I included all of the relevant C libraries and headers using `extern "C" {...}`. At first, I'd get errors on the include statements for the btstack files. I solved this by modifying the make file to include "INC = -I./directory/...". Next, I dealt with problems the g++ compiler found with the pasted C code (ex. adding spaces between literals and strings). After resolving those, it seems that none of the bstack files/functions are being linked properly as this is what I get when I attempt to "make":

["undefined reference to 'every single btstack function call in main.cpp'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIEIG.png)

My makefile. Note that a lot of this is probably unnecessary/does nothing. I was just trying anything and everything and borrowing lines from the btstack port makefile and seeing if they'd work.

```
CORE += \
    btstack_chipset_bcm.c \
    btstack_chipset_bcm_download_firmware.c \
    btstack_control_raspi.c \
    btstack_link_key_db_tlv.c \
    btstack_run_loop_posix.c \
    btstack_tlv_posix.c \
    btstack_uart_posix.c \
    btstack_slip.c \
    hci_dump_posix_fs.c \
    hci_transport_h4.c \
    hci_transport_h5.c \
    le_device_db_tlv.c \
    main.c \
    wav_util.c \
    btstack_stdin_posix.c \
    raspi_get_model.c \
    rijndael.c

.INCLUDE : home/pi/udpDemo/inc/btstack-master/example/Makefile.inc

CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 

SRC=$(wildcard ./src/*.cpp)
OBJ=$(patsubst ./src/%.cpp, ./obj/%.o, $(SRC))

INC=-I./inc \
    -I./inc/btsrc \
    -I./inc/btsrc/ble \
    -I./inc/btsrc/ble/gatt-service \
    -I./inc/platform/embedded \
    -I./inc/platform/posix \
    -I./inc/chipset/bcm \
    -I./inc/3rd-party/tinydir \
    -I./inc/3rd-party/rijndael \
    -I./inc/port/raspi \
    -I./src

LDFLAGS += -lrt
VPATH += src
VPATH += inc/3rd-party/rijndael
VPATH += inc
VPATH += inc/btsrc \
VPATH += inc/btsrc/ble \
VPATH += inc/btsrc/ble/gatt-service \
VPATH += inc/platform/embedded \
VPATH += inc/platform/posix \
VPATH += inc/chipset/bcm \
VPATH += inc/3rd-party/tinydir \
VPATH += inc/3rd-party/rijndael \
VPATH += inc/port/raspi \


LIBS=
TARGET=test
bindir=/usr/local/bin

$(TARGET):$(OBJ)
    $(CC)  -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) 

$(OBJ):./obj/%.o:./src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -I$(INC) 

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(OBJ)

install:$(TARGET)
    install -g root -o root $(TARGET) $(bindir)/$(TARGET)

uninstall:$(bindir)/$(TARGET)
    rm $(bindir)/$(TARGET)
```

Comment: Dumping another projects code into yours doesn't usually end well, especially when it's written in a different language.  Your best bet is usually to compile that other project's code into a library and then call that library from your own code.  Can you successfully compile the btstack code on its own?

Comment: Please don't post images or links to images in StackOverflow.  Cut and paste the information, properly formatted.

Comment: You have set `LDFLAGS` but you don't actually use it in your link line.  Also, `-I$(INC)` is wrong because the content of `INC` already has all the `-I` prefix.  Also, I have no idea what the `.INCLUDE` target is supposed to be doing: are you trying to `include` that file?  The basic problem is that you've not put the libraries (or object files) containing the definition of those symbols into your link command in your makefile.  Since we don't know where those symbols are defined we can't say more than that.

Comment: @bta : Noted. Btstack code compiles, runs, & works as intended on its own. I expanded on an example it included. Any suggestions on how I should compile it into a library & integrate?

Comment: @MadScientist  re: images: Noted, sorry. I figured this would be easier on the eyes. ```LDFLAGS``` - Forgive me, but what which is the link line? I'm very new to Makefiles/make. '''.INCLUDE''' - An admittedly pathetic attempt at getting it to work. Saw it online. The definitions of the symbols/functions called are scattered throughout a number of files within the btstack. What would be a good strategy for including these definitions in the link command?

Comment: @AlecLabadie The btstack documentation should explain how to build it into a library. You should end up with a `.a` file (the library) and some headers. Add a `-I/path/to/headers` argument when you call the compiler during your build. For the linker, add `-L/path/to/library` and `-lbtstack` (assuming the library is called 'libbtstack'). Don't try to build both out of one makefile, build them separately.

Comment: Based on your comments, it sounds like you're not very familiar with makefiles. This is a rather complicated project, and isn't a great place to learn about `make` (which itself is rather complicated).  I recommend building your code manually first, a crude shell script with `gcc` commands hard-coded.  Once you get it working, you can start cleaning it up and building a makefile. At the moment, you're wrestling `make` problems and build problems and it's hard to tackle both at once.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are both makefile issues and compile issues here.  Solving both at the same time is hard.  Below is a simplified and commented (but untested) version of your makefile that might be a good starting point for you.

Your original makefile looks like it was including a lot of stuff from the btstack build system.  It's usually not a good idea to mesh two separate projects together like that, both for technical and licensing reasons.  The typical way to use third-party code is to compile that code into a library and then have your code link against that library.  You'll have to consult the documentation for `btstack` for details on how to do that, I'm not familiar with that particular library.

```makefile
# Which compiler to use
CC=g++
# Options to pass to the compiler
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 

# Options to pass to the linker
LDFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS+=-lbtstack            # Link with 'libbtstack.a'
LDFLAGS+=-L/path/to/btstack   # Where to find the btstack libraries that were built separately

# Source files to compile (everything in 'src' directory)
SRC=$(wildcard src/*.cpp)
# Convert names of source files into their corresponding object files
OBJ=$(patsubst src/%.cpp, obj/%.o, $(SRC))

# Directories where headers are kept
INC=-Isrc
INC+=-I/path/to/btstack/headers

# Name of the program
TARGET=test

# Rule for linking the .o files together to build the program
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# Rule for making a .o file from a .cpp file
obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -I$(INC)

# Rule for deleting output and temporary files
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
```

This will compile all the `.cpp` files in your `src` directory and link them with `libbtstack.a` to create a program named `test`.  After you build the btstack library, update the `LDFLAGS` and `INC` variables with the actual paths to the btstack library and headers, respectively.